# JTextField#getText() returns "" for no reason

Tags: java, swing

```
class LaminaFoco extends JPanel{

JTextField cuadro1; 
JTextField cuadro2;
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
     setLayout(null);
     cuadro1=new JTextField();
     cuadro2=new JTextField();
     cuadro1.setBounds(120,10,150,20);
     cuadro2.setBounds(120,80,150,20);
     add(cuadro1);
     add(cuadro2);
     LanzaFocos foco=new LanzaFocos();
     cuadro1.addFocusListener(foco);
}



private class LanzaFocos extends FocusAdapter{

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String email=cuadro1.getText();
```

//rest of the code

For some reason, when I run this, the String email has the value "" and I don't understand why. Even stranger, it sometimes works properly.

Comment: Your code is completely wrong and you need to start over. A painting method is for painting only and nothing else. 1) You should NOT create components in the paintComponent() method. Every time the component is repainted a new text field will be created. 2) you should NOT create a listener either. Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There are sections on `How to Use Text Fields` or `Using Layout Managers` or `How to Write a FocusListener`. All sections have working examples.

Comment: Every time your panel is painted you create new fields. No wonder you're not getting the right text out of them.

Comment: I am following a tutorial and they did this in order to explain how the events work, and I copied it EXACTLY how they did it, but it works for them and not for me, the exact same code, and that is whats bothering me.

Comment: (1-) That tutorial in 100% wrong! You have been given a link to a proper tutorial

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the form-creation code in the constructor of your panel. The `paintComponents` is **not** intended for this.

*Or maybe even slightly more tasteful, in a new method (e.g. `protected void initContent()`) and then call that method from the constructor of your panel.*

You may also want to have a look at the official swing examples:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html

Specifically, what you are trying to do, is very similar to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java) example.

It's also worth taking a look at "ValueHolders" if you plan to make more complicated forms.

---

By contrast, if you are curious what the `paintComponents` method is for, it is actually for drawing, as illustrated by [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    redSquare.paintSquare(g);
}
```

Comment: But I still don't understand why it works for the guy in the video, but not for me, maybe because the video is 6-7 years old? But do things like this change? idk I am very new in java, and coding in general

Comment: @Memes This answer is exactly the same as the answer I provided in my original comment. Forget about the video, it is completely wrong. Don't waste any time trying to understand why it appears to work. Instead spend your time learning the proper way to use swing from the tutorial link that have now been given to you by two different people.

Comment: Alright, I will, thank you.